# Space navbar links evenly with padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar which utilizes drop down links. Currently it looks as follows:

[image]

The green part is the actual navbar and the grey part is the dropdown you get when you click any of the links.

I would like to space out the links in my nav bar so that they are evenly spaced with some padding on the left and right, kind of like this:

[image]

Right now here is how my code is structured:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
.navbar {
    background-color: #007953;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav.navbar-nav li a {
   color: white;
 }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #007953;
    color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #007953;
}

.nav > li.dropdown.open {
    position: static;
}
.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    display:table; width: 100%; text-align: center; left:0; right:0;
}
.dropdown-menu>li {
    display: table-cell;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: #49565A;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
  min-width: 400px;
  background-color: #49565A;
}
/* background-color here controls background of sub menu*/
.dropdown-menu.columns-3 {
  min-width: 600px;
  background-color: #49565A;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-transform: capitalize;

}
.dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
}

/* color tag here controls color of sub menu item's text*/
.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333;
  white-space: normal;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: yellow;
}

.caret {
  color: #9CCB3B;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    min-width: 240px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-header-->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Three Column <b class="caret" ></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Three Column <b class="caret" ></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Three Column <b class="caret" ></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
</nav>
<!--/.navbar-->


 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this without breaking any of the drop down functionality which I have implemented?

Answer (score 1):

I've added some modifications for you code. Hope this will work for you.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    .navbar {
        background-color: #007953;
        font-family: Arial;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
      .dropdown{
        margin-right:140px;
        margin-left:22px;
      }
    .nav.navbar-nav li a {
       color: white;
     }
      ..nav .navbar-nav{
        width:900px !important;
      }
      .nav .navbar-nav .dropdown{
          margin-right:200px;
      }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
        background-color: #007953;
        color: white;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
        color: white;
        background-color: #007953;
    }
    .nav > li.dropdown.open {
        position: static;
    }
    .nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
        display:table; width: 100%; text-align: center; left:0; right:0;
    }
    .dropdown-menu>li {
        display: table-cell;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
      min-width: 200px;
      background-color: #49565A;
    }
    .dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
      min-width: 400px;
      background-color: #49565A;
    }
    /* background-color here controls background of sub menu*/
    .dropdown-menu.columns-3 {
      min-width: 600px;
      background-color: #49565A;
      font-family: Arial;
      text-transform: capitalize;

    }
    .dropdown-menu li a {
      padding: 5px 15px;
      font-weight: 300;
      text-align: left;
    }

    /* color tag here controls color of sub menu item's text*/
    .multi-column-dropdown {
      list-style: none;
    }
    .multi-column-dropdown li a {
      display: block;
      clear: both;
      line-height: 1.428571429;
      color: #333;
      white-space: normal;
    }
    .multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: yellow;
    }

    .caret {
      color: #9CCB3B;
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
        min-width: 240px !important;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-header-->

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Three Column <b class="caret" ></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Three Column <b class="caret" ></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Three Column <b class="caret" ></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
    </nav>
    <!--/.navbar-->


     <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your modifications space out the menu items evenly. However, I was thinking maybe it can be set that  there is like 100px of space to the left and right of the nav bar links, and then everything in the middle is nav bar links spaced evenly. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Yes that can be possible by adjusting styles of the `ul` element and `navbar` items as well.

Comment: Do I add a margin or padding to the navbar, or do I add them to the ul?
 Any examples?